# How to use f1-score for CrossValidator evaluator in a binary problem(BinaryClassificationEvaluator) in pyspark 2.3

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

My use case is a common use case: binary classification with unbalanced labels so we decided to use f1-score for hyper-param selection via cross-validation, we are using pyspark 2.3 and pyspark.ml, we create a CrossValidator object but for the evaluator, the issue is the following:

- BinaryClassificationEvaluator does not have f1 score as evaluation metric.
- MulticlassClassificationEvaluator has f1 score, but is returning wrong results, my guess is it calculates f1 for every class(in this case just 2) and returns some kind of average across them, since the negative class(y=0) is predominant it generates high f1 but the model is really bad(f1 score for positive class is 0)
- MulticlassClassificationEvaluator added in recent versions the parameter evaluator.metricLabel which I think allows to specify which label to use(in my case I would set it to 1), but it is not available on spark 2.3

But the problem is: I use a corporate/enterprise spark cluster with no plans to upgrade current version(2.3) so the question is: how can I use f1 score in a CrossValidator evaluator for binary case considering we are restricted to spark 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class for this. I also had the same problem with my company's spark 2.4 so I tried to make an F1 score evaluator for binary classifications. I had to specify the `.evaluate` and `.isLargerBetter` methods for the new class. Here is a sample code when I tried on [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html) dataset :

```
class F1BinaryEvaluator():

    def __init__(self, predCol="prediction", labelCol="label", metricLabel=1.0):
        self.labelCol = labelCol
        self.predCol = predCol
        self.metricLabel = metricLabel

    def isLargerBetter(self):
        return True

    def evaluate(self, dataframe):
        tp = dataframe.filter(self.labelCol + ' = ' + str(self.metricLabel) + ' and ' + self.predCol + ' = ' + str(self.metricLabel)).count()
        fp = dataframe.filter(self.labelCol + ' != ' + str(self.metricLabel) + ' and ' + self.predCol + ' = ' + str(self.metricLabel)).count()
        fn = dataframe.filter(self.labelCol + ' = ' + str(self.metricLabel) + ' and ' + self.predCol + ' != ' + str(self.metricLabel)).count()
        return tp / (tp + (.5 * (fn +fp)))


f1_evaluator = F1BinaryEvaluator()

from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator
from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
gbt = GBTClassifier()
paramGrid = (ParamGridBuilder()
             .addGrid(gbt.maxDepth, [3, 5, 7])
             .addGrid(gbt.maxBins, [10, 30])
             .addGrid(gbt.maxIter, [10, 15])
             .build())
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=gbt, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, evaluator=f1_evaluator, numFolds=5)

cvModel = cv.fit(train)
cv_pred = cvModel.bestModel.transform(test)
```

The CV process ran with no problems, though I don't know about the performance. I also tried to compare the evaluator with `sklearn.metrics.f1_score` and the values are close.

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
print("made-up F1 Score evaluator : ", f1_evaluator.evaluate(cv_pred))
print("sklearn F1 Score evaluator : ", f1_score(cv_pred.select('label').toPandas(), cv_pred.select('prediction').toPandas()))

made-up F1 Score evaluator :  0.9363636363636364
sklearn F1 Score evaluator :  0.9363636363636363
```

Comment: This is great, I'm following this approach, I modified it a little bit to be able to use precision, recall and f1(passed as parameter in the constructor for example using metricName="f1") however i'm having some errors when calling functions like getMetricName(), do you know which other functions should i override to make it fully functional?

Comment: In case someone else has the same case: I made it work after adding some additional code for setting Params:
metricName = Param(Params._dummy(), "metricName",
                       "metric name in evaluation (areaUnderROC|areaUnderPR,precision,recall,f1)",
                       typeConverter=TypeConverters.toString)

Answer (score 1):

If you could use Spark v3.0+, the easiest way would be using `F-measure by label` metric and specifying the label (and setting beta to 1):

```
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName='fMeasureByLabel', metricLabel=1, beta=1.0)
```

But since you are restricted to v2.3, you can either

1. reimplement CrossValidator functionality. `pyspark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics` has `fMeasure` by label method. See the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#multiclass-classification) for reference.
2. change your metric to `areaUnderPR` from `BinaryClassificationEvaluator`, which is sort of "goodness of model" metric, and should do the job for you (re unbalanced labels).  This [blogpost](https://neptune.ai/blog/f1-score-accuracy-roc-auc-pr-auc) compares F1 and AUC-PR.